# Allow login with multiple passwords

Tags: lock-screens, security, password

Is it possible to setup multiple accepted passwords for the login to Android? Or perhaps an alternative secure login. (Note: facial recognition and fingerprint does *not* count as secure, but an RSA/NFC key would count.)

Like if I enter MySecretPassword1 it logs in, but it also accepts MyOtherPassword2.

I am looking for a phone (Note 2) solution, not a tablet. I am not looking for a multiple user account solution. My general use case is: I have a relatively simple password that I use day-to-day, but have a more complex password if I think someone is looking over my shoulder.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There is no real use of having multiple passwords unless you have multiple user accounts (can only be done on tablets).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - because I want to have an easy-to-remember and type password that I can use, but also a complex password that I can use if someone is watching over my shoulder/etc. and have it be hard if not impossible to remember (for them ofc)

Comment: This is off-topic, but on Windows Phone, AFAIK, you can have both a password and a PIN at the same time.

Comment: But on Android, I think you need a third-party solution.

Comment: I've incorporated the important information from your comments into the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run xposed framework, [NFC LockScreenOff Enabler](http://repo.xposed.info/module/pk.qwerty12.nfclockscreenoffenabler)  is your method of choice.